# Types of reductions and associated definitions of hardness

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, complexity-classes

Let A be reducible to B, i.e., $A \leq B$. Hence, the Turing machine accepting $A$ has access to an oracle for $B$. Let the Turing machine accepting $A$ be $M_{A}$ and the oracle for $B$ be $O_{B}$. The types of reductions:

- Turing reduction: $M_{A}$ can make multiple queries to $O_{B}$.
- Karp reduction: Also called "polynomial time Turing reduction": The input to $O_{B}$ must be constructed in polytime. Moreover, the number of queries to $O_{B}$ must be bounded by a polynomial. In this case: $P^{A} = P^{B}$.
- Many-one Turing reduction: $M_{A}$ can make only one query to $O_{B}$, during its the last step. Hence the oracle response cannot be modified. However, the time taken to constructed the input to $O_{B}$ need not be bounded by a polynomial.
  Equivalently: ($\leq_{m}$ denoting many-one reduction)

  > $A \leq_{m} B$ if $\exists$ a computable function $f: \Sigma^{\ast} \to \Sigma^{\ast}$ such that $f(x) \in B \iff x\in A$.
- Cook reduction: Also called "polynomial time many-one reduction": A many-one reduction where the time taken to construct an input to $O_{B}$ must be bounded by a polynomial.
  Equivalently: ($\leq^{p}_{m}$ denoting many-one reduction)

  > $A \leq^p_{m} B$ if $\exists$ a *poly-time* computable function $f: \Sigma^{\ast} \to \Sigma^{\ast}$ such that $f(x) \in B \iff x\in A$.
- Parsimonious reduction: Also called "polynomial time one-one reduction": A Cook reduction where every instance of $A$ mapped to a unique instance of $B$.
  Equivalently: ($\leq^{p}_{1}$ denoting parsimonious reduction)

  > $A \leq^p_{1} B$ if $\exists$ a *poly-time* computable bijection $f: \Sigma^{\ast} \to \Sigma^{\ast}$ such that $f(x) \in B \iff x\in A$.

  These reductions preserve the number of solutions. Hence $\#M_{A} = \#O_{B}$.

We can define more types of reductions by bounding the number of oracle queries, but leaving those out, could someone kindly tell me if I have gotten the nomenclature for the different types of reductions used, correctly.
Are NP-complete problems defined with respect Cook reduction or parsimonious reduction? Can anyone kindly give an example of a problem that is NP-complete under Cook and not under parsimonious reduction.

If I am not wrong, the class #P-Complete is defined with respect to Karp reductions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your definition of parsimonious reductions is incorrect. You are confusing it with polynomial-time one-one reductions which is a special case of Karp reductions. They don't preserve the number of "solutions". Please see [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2702/41) for more about reductions considering the number of certificates.

The rest seems fine although it is usually better to view them in a two dimensional chart:

- the complexity of reduction: computable, polynomial time, logarithmic space, etc.
- type of access: Turing, many-one, one-one, etc.

> Are NP-complete problems defined with respect Cook reduction or parsimonious reduction?

$\mathsf{NP}$ hardness and completeness are defined w.r.t. Karp reductions (polytime many-one), not Cook nor parsimonious reductions.

> Can anyone kindly give an example of a problem that is NP-complete under Cook and not under parsimonious reduction.

Take the complement of SAT, it is complete for $\mathsf{NP}$ under Cook reductions, it is not believed to be complete for $\mathsf{NP}$ under Karp reductions. Karp reductions include polytime one-one reductions.

> the class #P-Complete is defined with respect to Karp reductions

Note that [$\mathsf{\#P}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P) is not class of decisions problems, it is a class of function computation problems. Its hardness and completeness are usually defined w.r.t. Cook reductions (polytime Turing). See e.g. Arora and Barak, page 346.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to I have interchanged the "Karp reduction" and "Cook reduction" terminology. If I interchange it, then it matches your responses. Thanks. Regarding parsimonious reductions, are you saying that they do not preserve the number of "solutions" ? If so, I see in Theorem 17.10 of Arora & Barak (Page 299) that parsimonious reductions do indeed preserve the number of solutions. Another reference: (http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~andrejb/csc5170/notes/10L10.pdf)

Comment: Here it says a parsimonious reduction from L to SAT, maps every instance x of L to a unique instance of SAT (that is, reduction map is one-one): [http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~andrejb/csc5170/notes/10L10.pdf] . Isn't it right to assume that if the number of solutions are preserved by a reduction, then the map is one-one ?

Comment: @Pavithran, what you wrote in your question was not the definition of parsimonious reductions. For the answer, see the exercise 2.13 in their book.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of Karp reduction is incorrect. A Karp reduction is a polynomial-time  Turing reduction in which the oracle $O_B$ is called exactly once, during the reductions last step.

Comment: Specifically, the definitions of Cook and Karp reductions have been switched.