# Hardness of counting solutions to NP-Complete problems, assuming a type of reduction

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, complexity-classes

The $\text{NP-Complete}$ class of problems is defined w.r.t Karp Reductions, which are **polytime many-one reductions**. However, *they need not necessarily preserve the number of solutions*. A more restrictive type: **polytime one-one reductions** do indeed preserve the number of solutions.

Suppose $f:\Sigma^{\ast}\to \mathbb{N}$ is a counting function in $\text{#P}$ and the decision problem $f_{ > 0}$ defined as: **Is $f(x) > 0$ ?** is in $NP$.

Now if $f_{> 0}$ is in $\text{NP-Complete}$, can we immediately tell that $f$ is in $\text{#P-Complete}$ or, do we could only say so, if the reduction map (showing $\text{NP-Completeness}$) was **one-one**.

Comment: Up to my (poor :-) knowledge it is an open problem, i.e. an example of a polytime many-one reduction that cannot be made *parsimonious* (polytime one-one) has not been found yet. I think that further details can be found in [J. Simon. On the difference between one and many](http://www.springerlink.com/content/p847577u3013081h/)

Comment: "one-one" is not the correct terminology for what you are asking, one-one means that the reduction function is one-one regarding instances not certificates/solutions. Same is true about many-one, it is not about the number of solutions, it is about possibility of mapping several instances of the source problem to a single instance of the target problem. Note that Karp reductions and polytime one-one reductions make sense generally while the concept of certificate/solutions make sense only for *search problems*.

Comment: Don't confuse search problems, function problems, and decision problems. The correct statement of your question would be: **If the decision problem corresponding to a search problem is NP-complete, does it mean that the corresponding counting problem is #P-complete?**

Comment: @Vor, that paper is quite old and uses non-standard notations.

Comment: ps: we know that the reverse direction does not hold (unless strange things happens in complete theory, i.e. P=NP) since the counting version of Matching is #P-complete while the search version can be solved in polytime so decision version is in P.

Comment: @Kaveh: you are right, even "parsimonious reduction" (I used my comment above) is not correct. #P-hardness is defined using *weakly parsimonious reductions* (*counting reductions*). From [Algebraic Techniques for Satisfiability Problems](http://www.thi.uni-hannover.de/fileadmin/forschung/arbeiten/hschnoor-diss.pdf): "... In the constraint context, there are satisfiability problems, where the problem if a given formula has a solution at all is NP-complete, but the corresponding counting problem is not complete for #P under parsimonious reductions. ..."

Comment: @Vor, actually I am not sure that is the standard definition of #P-hardness, e.g. see Arora and Barak, definition 17.8, or [#P-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete) on Wikipedia. The definition in [Valiant's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(79)90044-6) is as follows: $A$ is #P-hard iff $\mathsf{FP}^A$ contains #P. The definition doesn't talk about preserving the number of solutions, however the proof of #P-completeness of #3SAT satisfies the condition.

Comment: @Kaveh: a *counting reduction* (or weakly parsimonious reduction) from counting problem $g$ to $f$ ($g \leq_c f$) is a pair of polytime functions $\sigma$, $\tau$ such that $|g(x)| = \tau(x,|f(\sigma(x))|)$ (it doesn't necessarily preserve the number of solutions). $f$ is #P-complete if it is in #P and $f \leq_c g$ for every $g \in \#P$. It seems equivalent to the oracle version in Arora and Barak; but the difference brings out if we consider only the *#P-hardness* definition. ?!?

Comment: @Vor, I don't follow the last part: "but the difference brings out if we consider only the #P-hardness definition. ?!?"

Comment: @Kaveh: I was only trying to express that the definition of #P-hardness under counting reductions (which I found in some papers) seems stronger than the Valiant's definition of #P-hardness.

Comment: @Vor Can I say that there are problems that are NP-Complete under Polytime many one reductions, but never under parsimonious reduction. I can refer to the example of CSF, following the extract you pointed out in [that article][1]. Surely, all #P Complete problems don't need to correspond to a NP-Complete decision problem. Isn't it equivalent to saying that parsimonious reductions cannot capture the entire #P-Complete class of problems (which is why we have a weaker notion of counting-reduction).
  [1]: http://www.thi.uni-hannover.de/fileadmin/forschung/arbeiten/hschnoor-diss.pdf

Comment: @Vor With reference to your first comment, the terms "polynomial many-one reductions" and "parsimonious reductions" are synonymous right ? I was confused, since apparently my definition [in this post][1] was not accurate for "parsimonious reductions".

[1]: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/types-of-reductions-and-associated-definitions-of-hardness

Comment: @PavithranIyer: (1) I wrote the first comment off the cuff: see Kaveh's notes after it. A *parsimonious reduction* from **counting problem** $f$ to $g$ is a polytime function $\sigma$ such that $|f(x)|=|g(\sigma(x))|$ (it preserves the number of solutions). (2) yes,  *parsimonious reduction* and *counting reduction* (see my comment above for its definition) lead to different sets (parsimonious reduction is stronger). (3) *Valiant's oracle reduction* ($g \in \#P$ is #P-complete if $\#P \subseteq FP^g$) and *counting reduction* lead to the same set of problems (THE #P-complete class).

Comment: @PavithranIyer: ... (4) (I think that) your question - if correctly reformulated as suggested by Kaveh - is still an open problem

Comment: @Vor Maybe summarize your comments into a short answer? It helps the site the less unanswered questions we have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an NP-complete problem, such that the decision version of its counting problem is not PP-complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66586/is-there-an-np-complete-problem-such-that-the-decision-version-of-its-counting)

Comment: @ThinhD.Nguyen I'm not seeing how a question about $\mathbf{\#P}$ is a duplicate of one about $\mathbf{PP}$ that doesn't seem to mention $\mathbf{\#P}$ anywhere in the question or its answers.

Comment: Ok, I retract the pending flag.